# Yet again: trouble with Broadcom Wireless Drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, 20.04, broadcom

I'm afraid the excellent and lengthy posts in 
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) are not solving my problem. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an mid 2007 24" iMac. But I'm a complete Ubuntu newbie. I'll try to make it as clear as possible what I tried and give you the info I have about the hardware.

So first of all: I have a Wifi connection but it's very poor. My iMac is on exactly the same spot where it was before and it had a full strength wifi signal. Now it has only half the strength and it drops out every other minute. I also have the impression that it influences the quality of the signal to my other devices (although I don't know if such a thing is at all possible). Same problem with the Bluetooth connection which drops out regularly.

My PCI.ID is

```
[14e4:4328] (rev 03)
```

which puts me in the `bcmwl-kernel-source` category, according to the Broadcom Wireless Table in the aforementioned discussion. If I understand correctly, this is the driver that came with Ubuntu and was checked in 'Additional Drivers'. Except it doesn't do the job.

Since it's after September 2014, I also installed the other package `firmware-b43-installer` after uninstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source`. To no avail. Then uninstalled that second package and turned back to the first one. Doesn't work.

I edited `blacklist.conf` to put a hashtag in front of `blacklist bcm43xx` and a lot of the other stuff suggested on the page. The problem is that I don't really have a way of knowing if I'm doing things in the right order since I'm completely new to Linux.

And yes, i have good intentions to inform myself and learn the basics of Linux. Which is (a.o.) why I need a good working wifi connection.

If somebody would be so kind to 'talk me through' the process, I would be very, very happy. This is my `wireless-info` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HF67Z2KWSh/

Many thanks!

Edit 1. I posted some more diagnostic data here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mt3RjjpQcQ/

Edit 2. Installing the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package made my wifi stop working altogether. Removing it brought me back to the same situation as before. So nothing solved yet.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall `firmware-b43-installer`. It is not a driver but a firmware pack. It down't spoil `wl`. Install `bcmwl-kernel-source` and post output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` and `dmesg | grep wl`. But according to your script output Wi-Fi is working now.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in @Pilot6. I posted the info you requested in a new Pastebin file (see my edit). As mentioned: the wifi is indeed working, but very faintly and all the time disconnecting/reconnecting.

Comment: I don't see that `bcmwl-kernel-source` is installed. Please run `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` and post the output. You need to be connected to the internet at that moment.

Comment: @Pilot6: I installed the bcmwl-kernel-source package and now I have no wifi at all. Not even after rebooting. I can see the networks, but no attempts seem to be made to connect. Since I have no internet on de iMac (I am writing this on the iPad) I cannot post the outputs. In “additional drivers” the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary) is selected.

Comment: You can post the output. You can connect using your phone, or save the output as a file, etc.

Comment: `04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03) // Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort EXtreme [106b:0088] // Kernel driver in use: wl // Kernel modules: ssb, wl`

Comment: `rfkill list // 0: phy0: Wireless LAN: Soft blocked: no // Hard blocked: no // 1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN: Soft blocked: no // Hard blocked: no // 2: hci0: Bluetooth: Soft blocked: no // Hard blocked: no`

Comment: `dmesg | grep wl: [12.038064] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel. // [12.038070] wl: module license MIXED/Proprietary taints kernel // [12.049470] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel // [12.053077] wl 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002) // [12.183151] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4328 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334) // [12.377957] wl 0000:04:00.0 wls4: renamed from wlan0`

Comment: Please don't add information to comments. [edit] your question. Well, it looks that `wl` is installed, but doesn't work. So remove `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: Understood. `bcmwl-kernel-source` removed. Reboot. Wifi back as it was before.